# Gui needed for hdparm/ Need help porting hdparm gui scripts from slackware to Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial!

Tags: scripts, hard-drive, ssd

I am currently working on a project involving this matter.

Parted Magic, a Slackware linux distrobution contains multiple scripts in their /usr/bin directory. the files are mostly called /usr/bin/pmagic* (were * is a wildcard).

These scripts make up a GUI menu with a "point and click" button mechanism. It is fairly cool and we uses these scripts to make wiping HDD and SSD disk with hdparm etc a piece of cake for standard users.

I want to port these to Ubuntu. I have zero knowledge of scripting as of yet. And i don't know how to port/install them.

Any help would be great and this would make Ubuntu way more of a swiss army knife for everyone if you know what i mean. We need to be able to securely wipe those ssd's.

Sincerely,

HALP

Comment: If you want help on porting a specific script directly, you should include the script's source code into your question (or link to a pastebin containing it). Alternatively, you could describe what a specific tool you know from PM does and ask how that could be implemented in any way in Ubuntu. However, you probably shouldn't ask about more than one script/tool per single question.

Comment: Hi http://pastebin.com/ephWfmgu Is this the code you were looking for? This is the "main" script but there are about 10 more scripts or so. thanks for the help. PS i am rather new to forums and posting source code etc, sorry for the inconvenience